# SQL Server - Pivot Table Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I display the following from the job history table

```
  SELECT 

    sum(run_duration) as [RUN_DURATION],          
         sysjobhistory.step_id,
         sysjobhistory.step_name
  FROM   msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
         INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs
           ON msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory.job_id = msdb.dbo.sysjobs.job_id
  WHERE  sysjobhistory.run_date <= Datepart(yyyy, @dateparam) * 10000 +
                                         Datepart(mm, @dateparam) * 100 +
                                  Datepart
                                  (
                                         dd, @dateparam)
         AND sysjobs.name = @JobName --remove this line if you want to show all jobs for the specified day
        AND step_id <> 0

-- AND run_status = 1
GROUP BY RUN_DATE, sysjobhistory.step_id,sysjobhistory.step_name
```

I want to display this in PIVOT FORMAT

For the Month - by Day for a specific Job - see the execution time for various steps (which Im getting about but not in PIVOT FORMAT)

Can anyone please help.

Regards

Comment: Do you have a fixed list of "Steps"?  I'm sure there are generators to build the query otherwise, but if you have a specific set of "Steps" based on their corresponding IDs, I could help out with SPECIFIC query instead of generic.

Comment: Steps are fixed - 10 steps executed in that job everyday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, move your query into a FROM (sub-select) query which I aliased the result as "PreQuery".  From this, for each Step you want to appear as a column is wrapped in a SUM( case/when ).  The "As" you should make/name to represent what that step is as the final column name.  I obviously don't have / know the steps and can't therefore force the final column name, but I think this gives you enough to work with.

As for the reason of the SUM() and GROUP BY of the outer query.  For each date, the inner query will return UP TO however many steps there are of data.  Since you want only a single row for the final per date, we have to create the cross-tab, thus grouping by just the date.  This is ok since there will only be one record per "step", the sum of a single instance will only give that value once.  If no such "step" is found, the value will be NULL (or 0 if you apply a COALESCE() on it.

Hope this makes sense.

```
select
      PreQuery.Run_Date,
      SUM( case when PreQuery.step_id = 1 then PreQuery.Run_Duration end )
         as Step1DescriptiveNameForColumn,
      SUM( case when PreQuery.step_id = 2 then PreQuery.Run_Duration end )
         as Step2DescriptiveNameForColumn,
      SUM( case when PreQuery.step_id = 3 then PreQuery.Run_Duration end )
         as Step3DescriptiveNameForColumn,
      SUM( case when PreQuery.step_id = 4 then PreQuery.Run_Duration end )
         as Step4DescriptiveNameForColumn,
      etc... for 5-10
   from 
      ( SELECT
              sjh.Run_Date,
              sjh.step_id,
              sjh.step_name,
              sum(sj.run_duration) as [RUN_DURATION]
           FROM
              msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory sjh
                 INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
                    ON sjh.job_id = sj.job_id
           WHERE
                  sjh.step_id <> 0
              AND sjh.run_date <= Datepart(yyyy, @dateparam) * 10000 
                               + Datepart(mm, @dateparam) * 100 
                               + Datepart(dd, @dateparam)
           GROUP BY 
              RUN_DATE,
              sjh.step_id,
              sjh.step_name ) PreQuery
```

group by 
      PreQuery.Run_date